Coefplot.gllvm shows different plots per categorical factor level rather than each factor
I'm not well versed in R but am using the GLLVM package to assess the influence of season and water mass on plankton distribution - when I try to make the coefficient plots using coeffplot.gllvm() I get a plot per factor level eg; season_factorSPRING or water_factorNeritic but I want a coeff plot for just the factors (season + water mass).
Also, the one level from each factor is missing (I assume this has become a reference level the others are based off but is this correct?)  - is there a way to do this? I have been following [https://jenniniku.github.io/gllvm/articles/vignette1.html#model-with-environmental-variables] as a guide and the only difference I can think of that is causing this issue is my data is categorical while the AntTraits dataset is numerical?
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Part of my code so far:
ALLData$water_factor <-factor(ALLData$water_type, 
                              levels = c("NW", "STW", "SAW"))
ALLData$season_factor<-factor(ALLData$season, 
                              levels = c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"))
 
data_ev <- ALLData[,c("station","Temp_avg","Sal_avg", "water_factor", "season_factor")]
head(data_ev)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  station Temp_avg Sal_avg water_factor season_factor
    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>        <fct>        
1       2    11.5     34.4 NW           Spring       
2       3    11.0     34.9 STW          Spring       
3       8     9.07    34.5 SAW          Spring       
4       9     8.58    34.3 SAW          Spring       
5       1    16.6     34.7 STW          Summer       
6       2    16.6     34.6 NW           Summer       

y <- as.matrix(data_zp)

X <- as.matrix(data_ev)
fit_env9<- gllvm(y,X, family = "negative.binomial", num.lv = 1,
                  formula = ~ season_factor + water_factor, seed = 1234)
coefplot.gllvm(fit_env9,cex.ylab = 0.7, mar = c(4,9,2,1), mfrow = c(2,2))

coefplot output - want two figures (season and water) not season and water broken by levels:


Yes, your assumption is correct. The missing factor levels are the reference levels (Autumn and NW).

Categorical variables in R are specified using contrasts. By default, R uses a "treatment" contrast, which means that categorical variables are transformed to dummy variables that indicate whether or not a certain category applies to an observation (i.e., a 0 or 1 for each observation). Since all information in a categorical variable can be summarized with all categories but one, one category can (and needs to) be dropped without loss of information. This is typically chosen alphabetically, but you can change that yourself by manually specifying the reference using the relevel function.
After fitting a model, you can still retrieve the estimated parameter for each category, but that requires a little work. Doing it yourself requires a thorough understanding of the model object, but fortunately there are various R-packages that can help you do it, the emmeans package being one of the popular choices. I recently wrote a function that allows using the emmeans package with gllvm model objects, which might make it into the package in the future.
I would rather not copy the code and post it here, since doing so is susceptible to future changes in the gllvm package (and I cannot be expected to keep it working here), but moderation of my reply has indicated this to be a requirement of stackoverflow, and it is not allowed to redirect to github. The function is:
recover_data.gllvm <- function(object, component = c("main", "LV"), ...){
 component <- match.arg(component)
  if(component == "main"){
    fcall <- getCall(object)
    X = object$X
    if(is.null(fcall$formula)){
      stop("Model without formula not yet implemented. Please refit your model using the formula argument.")
      # fcall$formula = as.formula(object$formula)
    }
  }else{
    fcall <- getCall(object)
    X = object$lv.X
    object$X <- X
    if(is.null(fcall$lv.formula)){
      stop("Model without lv.formula not yet implemented. Please refit your model using the formula argument.")
    }
    fcall$formula <- fcall$lv.formula
  }
  
 fcall$formula <- as.formula(paste0("~0+species+",paste0("species:", labels(terms(as.formula(fcall$formula))), collapse = "+")))
 X = cbind(data.frame(X,check.rows = FALSE),species = as.factor(rep(colnames(object$y),each=nrow(object$X))))
 frm = model.frame(fcall$formula, X)
 
  emmeans:::recover_data.call(getCall(object), trms = terms(fcall$formula), na.action = NULL, data = X, params = "pi", frame = frm, pwts = NULL, addl.vars = NULL)
}


emm_basis.gllvm = function(object, trms, xlev, grid, component = c("main", "LV"), ...){
  # if(is.null(object$call$formula)){
  #   fcall <- getCall(object)
  #   fcall$formula = as.formula(object$formula)
  #   fcall$formula <- as.formula(paste0("~0+",paste0(labels(terms(as.formula(fcall$formula))),":species",collapse = "+")))
  #   trms = terms(as.formula(object$formula))
  #   }
  component = match.arg(component)
  
  if(component == "main"){
    m = model.frame(trms, grid, na.action = na.pass, xlev = xlev)
    X = model.matrix(trms, m)
    
    bhat = cbind(object$param$beta0,object$params$Xcoef)
    V = vcov(object) # per species organized
    V <- V[row.names(V)=="b", colnames(V)=="b"]
    #reorder V to per covariate
    V <- V[order(rep(1:ncol(bhat),times=ncol(object$y))),order(rep(1:ncol(bhat),times=ncol(object$y)))]
  }else if((object$num.lv.c+object$num.RR)>0 && component == "LV"){
    m = model.frame(trms, grid, na.action = na.pass, xlev = xlev)
    X = model.matrix(trms, m)
    
    bhat = cbind(object$params$beta0, object$params$theta[,1:(object$num.lv.c+object$num.RR),drop=FALSE]%*%t(object$params$LvXcoef))
    V = gllvm:::RRse(object, return.covb = TRUE) # per covariate organised
    covMat <- object$Hess$cov.mat.mod
    colnames(covMat) <- row.names(covMat) <- names(object$TMBfn$par[object$Hess$incl])
    Sb <- covMat[colnames(covMat)=="b",colnames(covMat)=="b"]
    if(!object$beta0com){
      bidx <- rep(c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,ncol(Sb)/ncol(object$y)-1)), ncol(object$y))
    }else{
      bidx <- c(TRUE,rep(FALSE, ncol(Sb)-1))
    }
    Sb <- Sb[bidx,bidx]
    
    # Add covariances for intercept.
    K = ncol(object$lv.X.design)
    d = object$num.lv.c+object$num.RR
    p = ncol(object$y)

    covMat <- covMat[colnames(covMat)%in%c("b","b_lv","lambda"),colnames(covMat)%in%c("b","b_lv","lambda")]
    covMat <- covMat[c(bidx,rep(TRUE,sum(colnames(covMat)%in%c("b_lv","lambda")))),c(bidx,rep(TRUE,sum(colnames(covMat)%in%c("b_lv","lambda"))))]
    #add first row and column of zeros before b_lv, for first species
    covMat <- rbind(covMat[1:(p+d*K),, drop=FALSE],0,covMat[-c(1:(p+d*K)),, drop=FALSE])
    covMat <- cbind(covMat[,1:(p+d*K), drop=FALSE],0,covMat[,-c(1:(p+d*K)), drop=FALSE])
    
    if(d>1){
      idx<-which(c(upper.tri(object$params$theta[,1:d],diag=T)))[-1]
      
      #add zeros where necessary
      for(q in 1:length(idx)){
        covMat <- rbind(covMat[1:(p+d*K+idx[q]-1),],0,covMat[(p+d*K+idx[q]):ncol(covMat),])
        covMat <- cbind(covMat[,1:(p+d*K+idx[q]-1)],0,covMat[,(p+d*K+idx[q]):ncol(covMat)])
      }
    }
    row.names(covMat)[row.names(covMat)==""]<-colnames(covMat)[colnames(covMat)==""]<-"lambda"
    
    covLb <- covMat[colnames(covMat) =="lambda",colnames(covMat)=="b",drop=FALSE]
    if(object$beta0com){
      covLb <- do.call(cbind,replicate(ncol(object$y),covLB, simplify=FALSE))
    }
    covLB <- covMat[colnames(covMat)=="lambda",colnames(covMat)=="b_lv", drop=FALSE]
    covb_lvb <- covMat[colnames(covMat) =="b_lv",colnames(covMat)=="b",drop=FALSE]
    if(object$beta0com){
      covb_lvb <- do.call(cbind,replicate(ncol(object$y),covb_lvb, simplify=FALSE))
    }
    covBb <- matrix(0,  K*p,ncol(object$y))

    for(k in 1:K){
        for(j in 1:p){
          for(j2 in 1:p){
            for(q in 1:d){
              covBb[j+p*(k-1),j2] <- covBb[j+p*(k-1),j2]+object$params$LvXcoef[k,d]*covLb[j+p*(q-1),j2]+object$params$theta[j,q]*covb_lvb[(q-1)*K+k,j2]
            }
        }
        }
    }
  V = rbind(cbind(Sb,t(covBb)),cbind(covBb,V))
  }else{
    stop("Invalid model.")
  }

  nbasis=matrix(NA)
  dfargs = list(df = Inf)
  dffun <- function(k, dfargs)Inf
  
  list(X=X, bhat=c(bhat), nbasis = nbasis, V=V,dffun = dffun, dfargs = dfargs)
}

emmeans::.emm_register("gllvm","gllvm")

And here is an example of how to use it:
library(gllvm)
data(spider)
X = data.frame(covariate = rep(c("one","two","three","four"),7), soil.dry = spider$x$soil.dry)
model <- gllvm(spider$abund,X,formula=~covariate+soil.dry,family="poisson",num.lv=0)

emmeans(model, ~covariate:species)

But note that this is susceptible to change, and for future reference the associated gllvm github discussion topic should be consulted instead of copying the code from here.
In the example I have created an artificial covariate "covariate" for demonstration, and "species" does not need to be a covariate in the data (this is inferred from the responses provided to the model). The same function will work for a constrained ordination, but that required additionally passing component = "LV" to the emmeans function.
